# holomorphic function from the unit disc to itself with special point implies bound on $|f(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and suppose that $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ is a holomorphic function and that $f(\frac{1}{2})+f(-\frac{1}{2})=0$.

Prove that $f(0)\leq\frac{1}{4}$.

We can define the functions

$$\phi(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z},\ g(z)=\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2\phi(z)}$$

It is not so hard to obtain that $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $\frac{1}{2}$ and that $\forall z\in\mathbb{D}:|g(z)|\leq 1$.

Finally, $|g(0)|\leq 1$ and so $|f(0)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Can we get to $\frac{1}{4}$?

**Edit:**

Maybe we can use instead

$$\phi(z)=\frac{4z-1}{4-z},\ g(z)=\frac{f(2z)+f(-2z)}{2\phi(z)}$$

Comment: Consider $\phi(z)\cdot \phi(-z)$.

Comment: I now think that my second $\phi$ is enough since we get $|g(0)|\leq 1$ and so $4|f(0)|\leq 1$

Comment: $f(\pm 2z)$ is only defined for $\lvert z\rvert < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh, yes. So I should take $g(z)=\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2\phi(z)\cdot\phi(-z)}$ with the first $\phi$ and then remove two singularities. Thank you.